# Showing a popup dialog or custom popup view on click of a widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

Am trying to show a popup dialog or custom view on clicking of the widget (Something similar to quick contact badge). Am able to launch the Quick Contact badge on click of the widget but am not able to display this right next to the widget :(

Could you anyone give me any example source code to display a pop up dialog right next to the widget?

Comment: Does it just take you to the contacts page?  This sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530625/android-strange-behaviour-in-quickcontactbadge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this...

The quick contact badge can be displayed right next to the widget by getting the source bounds of the widget from intent that is used to launch the widget.

The method to be used for this is :-

intent.getSourceBounds();