# QuickContactBadge crashes app:

Tags: java, android, quickcontactbadge

I have searched around but none of the solutions worked for my specific case. If I add

```
QuickContactBadge contactBadge = (QuickContactBadge) findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge);
```

I it crashes. Then I changed it to:

```
    QuickContactBadge contactBadge;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ...

            contactBadge = (QuickContactBadge) findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge);
    }
```

And it doesn't crash. But if I add `contactBadge.Anything();` it crashes. No matter what
method it crashes. I.E. `contactBadge.assignContactFromEmail("foo@foo.com", true);`

Android Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            QuickContactBadge contactBadge;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new MainFragment()).commit();
                }

                contactBadge = (QuickContactBadge) findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge);
                contactBadge.assignContactFromEmail("pointlightproductions.net@gmail.com", true);
            }

            public static class MainFragment extends Fragment {

            public MainFragment() {

            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

                return rootView;
            }
        }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pointlight.android.kingdomcraft"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pointlight.android.kingdomcraft.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pointlight.android.kingdomcraft.MainActivity$MainFragment" >


    <QuickContactBadge
        android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you inflate the layout before using `findViewById`? Otherwise it returns `null`.

Comment: use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` and refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530625/android-strange-behaviour-in-quickcontactbadge)

Comment: yes I inflated, Its the default generated activity I just trimmed the method

Comment: the permission didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First method: You're calling `findViewById()` when the activity is instantiated and its member variables are initialized. The activity won't have a `Window` yet and it will NPE. Call `findViewById()` only in `onCreate()` or later, after `setContentView()`.

Second method: You don't have `setContentView()` with a view hierarchy that has a view with the given id. `null` is returned and invoking method on it will NPE.

From the code you later added, it seems the view is in your fragment layout and not the activity layout. It won't be a part of the activity view hierarchy in `onCreate()`. You should move the code to the fragment's `onCreateView()` instead:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
contactBadge = (QuickContactBadge) rootView.findViewById(R.id.quickContactBadge);
contactBadge.assignContactFromEmail("pointlightproductions.net@gmail.com", true);
```

Comment: I have setContentView it's for the most part the default generated activity, should I post my class?

Comment: Generally, yes, exception stacktrace, layout name used in `setContentView()` and the corresponding layout XML are relevant in further diagnosis.

Comment: well I didn't wan't to get critisized about proper question format, besides I am trying what Aksh posted

Comment: I fixed it, don't know why people here are so crabbby, post to much code get critisized, too little get critisized and still have to post more, in the end i still got down voted

Comment: I would rather not have it on my activity layout because then it could be viewed from every fragment/page